# Community user with customer community License not able to run Screen flow

Tags: community, visual-workflow, permissions, customer-community, visual-flows

I have created a screen flow and login flow.
Have called the screen flow from the login flow.
Login flow is configured to execute on community user login.
When the community user logs in, my login flow is getting executed but not screen flow.

I have given RUN FLOWS permission to the community user  profile and in the community Public Access Settings.

I don't see any errors / screen flow details in the debug logs.

Kindly suggest if I'm missing any settings here

Comment: Which type of Community License is being used? `Customer Community`, or `Customer Community Plus`? Is it a lightning community or a Visualforce & Tabs community?

Comment: @smitha were you able to see the figure out the root cause? I am also facing a similar issue with user license Customer Community Plus

Comment: Late answer but...
Have you tried with External Apps license?
Customer Community users don't seem to have permission to run flows (or at least have some limitations like the one you caught).